# How do I make a submit button that will send the information to my email?

Tags: html

I'm making a survey for my teacher to hand out to the class (he doesn't know how and I know more than he does)

My problem is I'm not too familiar with HTML and don't know how to get my submit button working.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<h2>
    Please fill this out as feedback.
</h2>
<body>
<form>
<form method="post" action='mailto:example_email@hostname.com'>
<input type="hidden" name="Re" value="survey">
<td>On a scale of 1-10, how well did you understand this tutorial?</td><br>
<td>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="q1">1
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="q1">2
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="q1">3
    <input type="radio" value="4" name="q1">4
    <input type="radio" value="5" name="q1">5
    <input type="radio" value="6" name="q1">6
    <input type="radio" value="7" name="q1">7
    <input type="radio" value="8" name="q1">8
    <input type="radio" value="9" name="q1">9
    <input type="radio" value="10" name="q1">10
</td>
<br>
<br>
<td>On a scale of 1-10, how much previous knowledge did you have before this tutorial?</td><br>
<td>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="q2">1
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="q2">2
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="q2">3
    <input type="radio" value="4" name="q2">4
    <input type="radio" value="5" name="q2">5
    <input type="radio" value="6" name="q2">6
    <input type="radio" value="7" name="q2">7
    <input type="radio" value="8" name="q2">8
    <input type="radio" value="9" name="q2">9
    <input type="radio" value="10" name="q2">10
</td>
<br>
<br>
<td>On a scale of 1-10, how comfortable do you think your skills are with the knowledge you learned?</td><br>
<td>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="q3">1
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="q3">2
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="q3">3
    <input type="radio" value="4" name="q3">4
    <input type="radio" value="5" name="q3">5
    <input type="radio" value="6" name="q3">6
    <input type="radio" value="7" name="q3">7
    <input type="radio" value="8" name="q3">8
    <input type="radio" value="9" name="q3">9
    <input type="radio" value="10" name="q3">10
</td>
<br>
<br>
<td>On a scale of 1-10, how likely are you to ever use HTML again?</td><br>
<td>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="q4">1
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="q4">2
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="q4">3
    <input type="radio" value="4" name="q4">4
    <input type="radio" value="5" name="q4">5
    <input type="radio" value="6" name="q4">6
    <input type="radio" value="7" name="q4">7
    <input type="radio" value="8" name="q4">8
    <input type="radio" value="9" name="q4">9
    <input type="radio" value="10" name="q4">10
</td>
<br>
<br>
<td>On a scale of 1-10, did you enjoy taking part in this?</td><br>
<td>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="q5">1
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="q5">2
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="q5">3
    <input type="radio" value="4" name="q5">4
    <input type="radio" value="5" name="q5">5
    <input type="radio" value="6" name="q5">6
    <input type="radio" value="7" name="q5">7
    <input type="radio" value="8" name="q5">8
    <input type="radio" value="9" name="q5">9
    <input type="radio" value="10" name="q5">10
</td>
<br>
<br>
Please include your thoughts, sugestions, or questions here:<BR>
<TEXTAREA NAME="Comments" ROWS="6" COLS="50"></TEXTAREA>
<br>
<br>

<td><input type="submit" value="Send"></td>
</form>
</body>
```

I'm sorry if it's messy, I'm just trying to throw this together and I'm not so great with HTML as it is.

Where I have example_email@hostname.com, I have my real email there.

Thanks!

Comment: So you know more than your teacher but you are not familiar with HTML? Cool.

Comment: My teacher does not teach this stuff, thats why im getting it for him.

Answer (score 2):

First remove the duplicate `<form>` tag.

```
<form><!-- remove this -->
<form method="post" action='mailto:example_email@hostname.com'>
```

If you are just trying call up the user's email client to send an email, you can do this:

```
<form action='mailto:example_email@hostname.com' method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

Any further than that you will need some kind of server-side language to process the data being submitted.

Here's what you can do in PHP:

```
<form method="post" action="survey.php">
```

```
<?php
// You can retrieve the values this way. You may want to sanitize the input as well.
$question1 = $_POST['q1'];
$question2 = $_POST['q2'];
$question3 = $_POST['q3'];
$question4 = $_POST['q4'];
$question5 = $_POST['q5'];
$question6 = $_POST['q6'];
$comments  = $_POST['Comments'];
?>
```

Comment: So how would i implement that into my code?

Comment: @user2462068 You should go with the email method at the moment. As for the PHP method, you will need to have a server/host that can run PHP. You may want to learn the basics of HTML and PHP before you implement this. There should be quite some tutorials on processing forms using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There's some syntax error in your code. You're using `<form>` tag 2 times. You should remove the first `<form>` tag.

Also you should add `enctype="text/plain"` in your `form`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer php in that case.
Here, an awesome tutorial on this.

http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

You also able to download this source from [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebsiteChangeRequestForm.zip) and checkout the [demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebsiteChangeRequestForm/).